# Customer login observer not working on Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, configuration, model

When a user logged in,automatically is redirected to the Dashboard page, but i want to stay on the same page from where he logged in  successfully.

For this a created 2 observers but none of them working. 
I tried to print_r something at the begining at each function, but without success

My config xml looks like this:

```
<global>
        <helpers>
            <in2itive_customerredirect>
                <class>In2itive_CustomerRedirect_Helper</class>
            </in2itive_customerredirect>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <in2itive_customerredirect>
                <class>In2itive_CustomerRedirect_Model</class>
            </in2itive_customerredirect>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
             <customer_login>
                    <observers>
                        <in2itive_customerredirect_customer_login>
                            <class>In2itive_CustomerRedirect_Model_Observers_Customer_Redirect</class>
                            <method>customerLoginRedirect</method>
                        </in2itive_customerredirect_customer_login>
                    </observers>
             </customer_login>

            <controller_action_predispatch>
                    <observers>
                        <in2itive_customerredirect_controller_action_predispatch>
                            <class>In2itive_CustomerRedirect_Model_Observers_Customer_Lastpage</class>
                            <method>getLastVisitedPage</method>
                        </in2itive_customerredirect_action_predispatch>
                    </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

and my observers are located in  **app\code\local\In2itive\CustomerRedirect\Model\Observers\Customer\Lastpage.php** and it looks like this :

```
 /**
     * @param $observer
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function getLastVisitedPage($observer)
    {   echo 1; exit();
        $this->_beforeLogin($observer);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the lastest url visited by a user, in a session,  if it is not logged in
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function _beforeLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   print_R(1); die();
        $url = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
        if ((strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()) !== 0)
            && (strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, true)) !== 0)
        ) {
            $url = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        }

        $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
        if (strpos($url, 'customer/account') === false && strpos($url, 'skin') === false) {
            $session->setData("lastUrl", $url);
        }
    }
```

and the second one located on the same location looks like this:

```
class In2itive_CustomerRedirect_Model_Observers_Customer_Redirect extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @param $observer
     *
     * @return $this
     */
     public function redirectCustomer($observer){
         print('sadasd'); die();
    $url = 'http://www.google.ro';
    // $url can be : Mage::getUrl('some/path'); or Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'some-cms-page.html'));
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    return $this;
}


    public function customerLoginRedirect($observer)
    {   print_r("dsadasd"); die();
        $this->_redirectUser($observer);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Getting the latest url from session and the redirects the user after the login process to the latest url visited
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function _redirectUser(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $sessionUrl = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $lastUrl = $sessionUrl->getData("lastUrl");
        $lastUrl = str_replace("/onepage/","",$lastUrl);   
        print_R($lastUrl); die();
        $session->setAfterAuthUrl($lastUrl);
    }

}
```

What i am doing wrong? why my observer is not accessed?

Comment: Try creating Observer.php file in Model folder and call all your method inside that file.

Comment: i tried but withot success. thank you anyway.

Comment: can you post your entire module code somewhere on github?

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done via configuration:
You need to change the option:

```
System > Config > Customer > Costumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in
```

to NO